# Facebook Messenger Chatbot Custom Event Tracking

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I am trying to log custom events with a Facebook Chatbot I have developed, however I cannot for the life of me find a reference for the `custom_events` types.

The example listed [on their reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/bots-for-messenger) shows `fb_mobile_purchase` as a custom eventName. I don't want that, and I can't find anywhere that lists other types.

I want to be able to track when the chatbot sends the user a specific message, but just setting the `eventName` to anything results in an event name in the Analytics as `Reserved5`.

Is there a reference to eventNames anywhere within Facebook Documentation?

Comment: The very definition of “custom” here is that _you_ specify how the event should be named. _“I want to be able to track when the chatbot sends the user a specific message”_ – why would you need to track that using events? It is _your bot_ that sent the message, so you already know that it has happened.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I stated above, the custom name shows up as `Reserved5` in the analytics. I need to be able to track when a specific message is sent to the user, as it stands, the analytics only says that _any_ message was sent, but not what that message was.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [Chatbase](http://chatbase.com) for bot analytics (free to use), which has a [Custom Events API](https://chatbase.com/documentation/events).

Answer (score 0):

Currently [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/bots-for-messenger) give this as an example request:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({ 
  url : "https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/activities",
  form: {
    event: 'CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS',
    custom_events: JSON.stringify([{
      _eventName: "fb_mobile_purchase",
      _valueToSum: 55.22,
      _fb_currency: 'USD'
    }]),
    advertiser_tracking_enabled: 0,
    application_tracking_enabled: 0,
    extinfo: JSON.stringify(['mb1']),
    page_id: <page_id>,
    page_scoped_user_id: recipientId
  }
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
  console.error(err);
  console.log(httpResponse.statusCode);
  console.log(body);
});
```

So, when the bot is sending that specific message you want to keep an eye out for, fire that message but with a different `_eventName`, and if needed other parameters.

Keep in mind, by `recipientId` they mean the PSID of the user the bot is sending the message to.